# Why should the last tag be fixed in CRF?

Tags: conditional-random-field

In the [tutorial](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5f5c/171b07540cf739485967cab50fc00dd26ae1.pdf), it is said that:

> Let v range over the tags. Define U(k, v) to be the score of the best
>   sequence of tags from 1 to k, where tag k is required to be v. This is
>   a maximization over k −1 tags because tag number k is fixed to have
>   value v

It is very confusing that why should the Kth tag be fixed?

Comment: v is the STOP tag, and the sequence needs to end with a STOP tag.

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10715-f18/lectures/lecture2-crf.pdf#page=84) that the first and last tokens are all fixed.

[image]